# Conflict between two scripts acting on the same element (option tag) using jquery .on() methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

Im having a conflict. I wrote a simple script which filter divs based on class names. It works but not when I add a third party script. The relevant lines here are the .on functions. The third party code inhibits my code from functioning. Both target option tags in the html code.

I tried removing the "return false" in my code with no success. Tried putting my code to the top...nothing. I thought about using `event.stopPropagation()`. I read about it. Could this work in my case and how do I integrate it?

I would like to provide a functional jsfiddle but unfortunately im not so trained using hat website as im more used to notepad++ and dreamweaver.

Here is my custom script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {
    var t = e("#filter-container");
    t.imagesLoaded(function () {
        t.isotope({
            itemSelector: "figure",
            filter: "*",
            resizable: false,
            animationEngine: "jquery"
        })
    });
    $("select").on("change", function () {
        var select = $(this);
        var selectedOption = select.find("option:selected");
        var r = selectedOption.attr("data-filter");
        t.isotope({
            filter: r
        });
        return false
    });
    e(window).resize(function () {
        var n = e(window).width();
        t.isotope("reLayout")
    }).trigger("resize")
});
```

and there is the third party script:

```
(function ($, window, undefined) {   
    'use strict';

    $.DropDown = function (options, element) {
        this.$el = $(element);
        this._init(options);
    };

    // the options
    $.DropDown.defaults = {
        speed: 300,
        easing: 'ease',
        gutter: 0,
        // initial stack effect
        stack: true,
        // delay between each option animation
        delay: 0,
        // random angle and positions for the options
        random: false,
        // rotated [right||left||false] : the options will be rotated to thr right side or left side.
        // make sure to tune the transform origin in the stylesheet
        rotated: false,
        // effect to slide in the options. value is the margin to start with
        slidingIn: false,
        onOptionSelect: function (opt) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    $.DropDown.prototype = {

        _init: function (options) {

            // options
            this.options = $.extend(true, {}, $.DropDown.defaults, options);
            this._layout();
            this._initEvents();

        },
        _layout: function () {

            var self = this;
            this.minZIndex = 1000;
            var value = this._transformSelect();
            this.opts = this.listopts.children('li');
            this.optsCount = this.opts.length;
            this.size = {
                width: this.dd.width(),
                height: this.dd.height()
            };

            var elName = this.$el.attr('name'),
                elId = this.$el.attr('id'),
                inputName = elName !== undefined ? elName : elId !== undefined ? elId : 'cd-dropdown-' + (new Date()).getTime();

            this.inputEl = $('<input type="hidden" name="' + inputName + '" value="' + value + '"></input>').insertAfter(this.selectlabel);

            this.selectlabel.css('z-index', this.minZIndex + this.optsCount);
            this._positionOpts();
            if (Modernizr.csstransitions) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    self.opts.css('transition', 'all ' + self.options.speed + 'ms ' + self.options.easing);
                }, 25);
            }

        },
        _transformSelect: function () {

            var optshtml = '',
                selectlabel = '',
                value = -1;
            this.$el.children('option').each(function () {

                var $this = $(this),
                    val = isNaN($this.attr('value')) ? $this.attr('value') : Number($this.attr('value')),
                    classes = $this.attr('class'),
                    selected = $this.attr('selected'),
                    label = $this.text();

                if (val !== -1) {
                    optshtml += classes !== undefined ?
                        '<li data-value="' + val + '"><span class="' + classes + '">' + label + '</span></li>' :
                        '<li data-value="' + val + '"><span>' + label + '</span></li>';
                }

                if (selected) {
                    selectlabel = label;
                    value = val;
                }

            });

            this.listopts = $('<ul/>').append(optshtml);
            this.selectlabel = $('<span/>').append(selectlabel);
            this.dd = $('<div class="cd-dropdown"/>').append(this.selectlabel, this.listopts).insertAfter(this.$el);
            this.$el.remove();

            return value;

        },
        _positionOpts: function (anim) {

            var self = this;

            this.listopts.css('height', 'auto');
            this.opts.each(function (i) {
                $(this).css({
                    zIndex: self.minZIndex + self.optsCount - 1 - i,
                    top: self.options.slidingIn ? (i + 1) * (self.size.height + self.options.gutter) : 0,
                    left: 0,
                    marginLeft: self.options.slidingIn ? i % 2 === 0 ? self.options.slidingIn : -self.options.slidingIn : 0,
                    opacity: self.options.slidingIn ? 0 : 1,
                    transform: 'none'
                });
            });

            if (!this.options.slidingIn) {
                this.opts.eq(this.optsCount - 1)
                    .css({
                    top: this.options.stack ? 9 : 0,
                    left: this.options.stack ? 4 : 0,
                    width: this.options.stack ? this.size.width - 8 : this.size.width,
                    transform: 'none'
                })
                    .end()
                    .eq(this.optsCount - 2)
                    .css({
                    top: this.options.stack ? 6 : 0,
                    left: this.options.stack ? 2 : 0,
                    width: this.options.stack ? this.size.width - 4 : this.size.width,
                    transform: 'none'
                })
                    .end()
                    .eq(this.optsCount - 3)
                    .css({
                    top: this.options.stack ? 3 : 0,
                    left: 0,
                    transform: 'none'
                });
            }

        },
        _initEvents: function () {

            var self = this;

            this.selectlabel.on('mousedown.dropdown', function (event) {
                self.opened ? self.close() : self.open();
                return false;

            });

            this.opts.on('click.dropdown', function () {
                if (self.opened) {
                    var opt = $(this);
                    self.options.onOptionSelect(opt);
                    self.inputEl.val(opt.data('value'));
                    self.selectlabel.html(opt.html());
                    self.close();
                }
            });

        },
        open: function () {
            var self = this;
            this.dd.toggleClass('cd-active');
            this.listopts.css('height', (this.optsCount + 1) * (this.size.height + this.options.gutter));
            this.opts.each(function (i) {

                $(this).css({
                    opacity: 1,
                    top: self.options.rotated ? self.size.height + self.options.gutter : (i + 1) * (self.size.height + self.options.gutter),
                    left: self.options.random ? Math.floor(Math.random() * 11 - 5) : 0,
                    width: self.size.width,
                    marginLeft: 0,
                    transform: self.options.random ?
                        'rotate(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 11 - 5) + 'deg)' : self.options.rotated ? self.options.rotated === 'right' ?
                        'rotate(-' + (i * 5) + 'deg)' :
                        'rotate(' + (i * 5) + 'deg)' : 'none',
                    transitionDelay: self.options.delay && Modernizr.csstransitions ? self.options.slidingIn ? (i * self.options.delay) + 'ms' : ((self.optsCount - 1 - i) * self.options.delay) + 'ms' : 0
                });

            });
            this.opened = true;

        },
        close: function () {

            var self = this;
            this.dd.toggleClass('cd-active');
            if (this.options.delay && Modernizr.csstransitions) {
                this.opts.each(function (i) {
                    $(this).css({
                        'transition-delay': self.options.slidingIn ? ((self.optsCount - 1 - i) * self.options.delay) + 'ms' : (i * self.options.delay) + 'ms'
                    });
                });
            }
            this._positionOpts(true);
            this.opened = false;

        }

    }

    $.fn.dropdown = function (options) {
        var instance = $.data(this, 'dropdown');
        if (typeof options === 'string') {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
            this.each(function () {
                instance[options].apply(instance, args);
            });
        } else {
            this.each(function () {
                instance ? instance._init() : instance = $.data(this, 'dropdown', new $.DropDown(options, this));
            });
        }
        return instance;
    };

})(jQuery, window);
```

What could this be?

I hope someone can enlighten me. Im currently trying to create a site for my smaller brother who is currently very sick. He always wanted a music website so I thought I just create one for him. The only factor blocking me from publishing it is this conflict between those two scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the long chat on the comments...

The third party `script` is a plugin to apply effects on `dropdowns` (`selects`). Basically it *converts* the attached element into a `ul` and stick each `option` there as a `li`.

In your piece of code, you're trying to retrieve the selected `value` by checking which `option` is selected, and this won't work anymore.
The plugin keeps the selected `value` in a `hidden field`.

I would change your code to something like this:

```
$(function () {
    var t = $("#filter-container");

    t.imagesLoaded(function () {
        t.isotope({
            itemSelector: "figure",
            filter: "*",
            resizable: false,
            animationEngine: "jquery"
        });
    });        

    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        var n = $(this).width();

        t.isotope("reLayout");        
    }).trigger("resize");
});
```

---

Then look in your page for the code below and change it:

```
$(function () {
    $('#cd-dropdown').dropdown({
        gutter : 5,
        onOptionSelect: function (opt) {
            $("#filter-container").isotope({
                filter: opt.data('value')
            });
        }
    });
});
```

---

The `isotope` filter works on classes that you've set in your `select` `options`, but as the plugin got rid of it and replaced with the `ul`, this data is now lost.

To make it work, you'll need to slightly change your `select` markup:

```
<select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
    <option value="*" selected>Pick a Genre</option>
    <option value="*">All</option>
    <option value=".epic">Epic</option>
    <option value=".classic">Classic</option>
    <option value=".regional">Regional</option>
    <option value=".electronic">Electronic</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I was thinking that the third party code was really hard to maintain so I created my own drop down script. Works standalone but again seems to fail in conjuction with isotope : (. Tried applying the upper method with jquery click events but didnt work. The code is really small, maybe you want to have a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26316109/click-events-from-two-scripts-on-same-element

Comment: the solution yesterday was not for nothing though because I learned how to handle a conflict between option selecting.